# Ng-repeat freeze with pagination

Tags: pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, freeze

I am using ng-repeat to create html table ,in some case I have huge data like 11k rows ,but I am ok with using pagination . SO I am displaying only 25rows per page. But in my case  broswer still freezes when I get the response from backend. I am using something like this

```
   <tbody ng:repeat="airport in (filteredList = (orderList(list)) | startFrom:     ((currentPage-1)*pageSize) | limitTo:pageSize)">
```

This is a plunker link[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3kXXGIr5bDCboxTVt4Ul?p=preview). Here it seems to be working fine ,my problem is it freezes when it started rendering table rows, even though it only has to render 25 rows (ie per page records) even all my watchers are set for current page records only . Am I missing something here. Inter page navigation is fine though.

Comment: That's far too speculative for a concise answer. Please provide a live example for your use case.

Comment: <tbody ng:repeat="airport in (filteredList = (orderList(list) | filter:search:entityTableFilter | countryFilter : country | cityFilter : city ) | startFrom:((currentPage-1)*pageSize) | limitTo:pageSize)">

Comment: Instead of pasting code into comments, please edit your actual question to make it more specific and more likely to be answered. Also, a snippet or a link to a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is greatly appreciated. You can instantly add AngularJS as a library there.